# Plotting an interaction with confidence intervals from an lme4 or LmerTest model in R

Tags: r, lme4, interaction, sjplot, lmertest

Using `dat` (found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NT2Ln2LbwbRDw9t30bVVk8loyE-jyAZU4iNTv-A5oM0/edit?usp=sharing)), I run the following model:

```
library(lmerTest)

model <- lmerTest::lmer(eval ~ post + ess + post*ess + (1|ID), data = dat)
```

The output of `summary(model)` indicates the interaction term is significant:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: eval ~ post + ess + ess * post + (1 | ID)
   Data: dat

REML criterion at convergence: 163.4

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.95714 -0.48596  0.00623  0.49208  1.82729 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID       (Intercept) 0.33344  0.5774  
 Residual             0.02944  0.1716  
Number of obs: 170, groups:  ID, 85

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value             Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.50194    0.09082 90.00645  16.538 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
post        -0.24537    0.03658 83.00000  -6.707        0.00000000226 ***
ess          0.15444    0.13076 90.00645   1.181              0.24067    
post:ess     0.15620    0.05267 83.00000   2.965              0.00395 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
         (Intr) post   ess   
post     -0.201              
ess      -0.695  0.140       
post:ess  0.140 -0.695 -0.201
```

But when I try to plot the interaction using `sjPlot` using 95% confidence intervals, the resulting intervals don't make the interaction look significant at all...

```
library(sjPlot)
library(TMB)

plot_model(model, type="int", ci.lvl=0.95)
```

[image]

My two questions:

1. Why do the estimates and the plotted results appear to tell different stories?
2. How can I extract confidence intervals for coefficients from the model to create my own graph instead of using `plot_model()`? I would like to make a bar plot to illustrate the interaction because the variables `ess` and `post` are binary.

Note: I'm happy to use `lme4` - should get to the same result, it is just not as obvious what coeficients are significant when lme4 objects are summarized and I wanted the question to be very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer your questions in reverse order:

2. The `plot_model()` function calls functions from the `ggeffects` package. Specifically, `ggpredict()` does a lot of the work. If you go to the following URL, you will find lots of information on how to alter effects plots and getting all sorts of information from the fitted model.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggeffects/vignettes/ggeffects.html

1. I don't really agree that the interaction does not look significant. The confidence interval doesn't overlap with the other categories mean for the majority of the plot. That might be beside the point, however, as you are currently plotting categorical data in a manner that makes it look continuous. This does not change how the model is being fit under the hood, but it changes the default behaviour of `sjPlot`. I have fit the model you specified with factors and plotted it how I think it should be plotted below. I don't think this changes much about the plot, but it might change your interpretation. The difference shown here in this plot is consistent with the model summary output and can be stated like this: the difference between the two levels of `post` is not the same when `ess` is a 0 vs. a 1. Also, see how the CIs of the two `ess` categories overlap with the mean when `post` is 0 but they are significantly different when `post` is 1.

Let me know if any of this requires further clarification.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - put differently, even in a barplot equivalent (what I'm trying to make) where bar heights are equal to post - pre where ess=0 and then ess=1 should show non-overlapping confidence intervals. For means to be significantly different, the confidence intervals of the estimated means themselves (not just interval of one group vs point estimate for another) should not overlap at least at some point. Perhaps the confidence intervals for estimated mean differences are different than estimated means, and what I'm plotting now is the latter when I actually need the former?

Comment: I don't believe that confidence intervals need to not overlap. They just need to not overlap with the conditional mean of the other category